# How to rotate a 3d curve relative to a straight line

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have a curve

```
ax.plot(xvals, yvals, zvals)
```

Where

```
xvals=[x1, x2, x3 ...], yvals=[y1, y2, y3 ...], zvals=[z1, z2, z3 ...]
```

And I have a straight line given by two points

```
[x_begin,y_begin,z_begin], [x_end,y_end,z_end]
```

How to rotate curve 90/180/270 degrees relative to straight (clockwise or not — it doesn't matter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982877/opengl-rotation-of-an-object-around-a-line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842090/rotate-line-around-center-point-given-two-vertices/14842362